# In the Buffy episode Consequences, how did Angel get into Faith's apartment?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

I don't recall him going there before, but I could be wrong. He bursts in to save Xander uninvited.

Comment: Just to clarfy, since it isn't directly stated in the question: in the Buffyverse, vampires need to be invited by the homeowner or someone living there in order to enter a private residence otherwise they'll just bounce off an invisible barrier. They do not need an invitation for places open to the public.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In "Consequences", Faith was living in a motel room, not an apartment. As such, it was not a private residence- rather it qualifies as a public place which vampires don't need invitation for.

Some further info on [vampire invitations](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire#Invitations) in Buffy.

Comment: Oh, cool. I didn't realise!